# Can a process be capable of creating a new socket but not have the permission to access it?

Tags: c, linux, centos7

I am running a client code in CentOS. My process is able to create a socket successfully, but a bind() or connect() call to the socket return EACCES error. Verified that the O_RDWR flag is set on the socket. I am running the process as root

```
#define SA struct sockaddr 

int sockfd, connfd; 
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

// socket create and verification 
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sockfd == -1) { 
    printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

// assign IP, PORT 
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("x.x.x.x"); 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(x); 

// connect the client socket to server socket 
if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
    printf("connection with the server failed with error: %d\n",errno); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else printf("connected to the server..\n");
```

Output:

```
Socket successfully created
connection with the server failed with error:13
```

Comment: please edit your Q to include the smallest amount of code that demonstrates your problem. Good luck.

Comment: What do you expect to get from `inet_addr("x.x.x.x");`?

Comment: Did you read the [Linux `connect` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) to see why `connect` can fail with `errno == EACCESS`?  And eliminate those possibilities?

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("connection with the server failed with error: %d\n",errno);` and `printf("socket creation failed...\n");`   This doesn't tell the user the reason for the failure.  Suggest: calling `perror( "your error message" );`  as this outputs to `stderr` both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.